# calling a function to print something

Tags: python, list, function, max, min

I am having trouble trying to print everything in my `printResults` function. I'm not sure on how to print the `max` and `min` values and their `index` location using the `printResults` function without having to input the `num` and `index` arguments in it because I'm calling that function to find those things. Here is my code:

```py
def minValue(numbers):
    num_min = numbers[0]
    location = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] < num_min:
            num_min = numbers[i]
            location = i
    return (num_min, location)
    
def maxValue(numbers):
    num_max = numbers[0]
    location = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] > num_max:
            num_max = numbers[i]
            location = i
    return (num_max, location)

def printResults(flag, num, index):
    if flag == 0:
        print("The min value is  ", num, ", it's at index ", index, ".")
    else:
        print("The max value is  ", num, ", it's at index ", index, ".")

def printList(nums):
        last_element = nums[len(nums)-1]
        for i in nums:
            if last_element == i:
                print(i, end=".")
            else:
                print(i, end=", ")
        print()

def createList(start=0, end=50, increment=1):
    nums = []
    for i in range(start, end, increment):
            nums.append(i)
    random.shuffle(nums)
    return nums
```

And this is my code to call the functions and print things:

```py
#create a list of numbers which are multiples of 3, between 3 and 50
theList = (createList(3, 51, 3))
printList(theList)
minNum = minValue(theList)
maxNum = maxValue(theList)
print(minNum)
print(maxNum)
```

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify, and please write a more descriptive title. If you're looking for debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including minimized code, expected output, and actual output (or if you get an error, the full error message with traceback).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to call the `printResults()` function (there are better ways), then you need to realise that the index is also being returned from the `minValue()` and `maxValue()` functions and you should capture these in their own variable:

```py
minNum, minIndex = minValue(theList)
maxNum, maxIndex = maxValue(theList)
printResults(0, minNum, minIndex )
printResults(1, maxNum, maxIndex )
```